# Can I use a Custom Method Annotations in Retrofit 2.0?

Tags: retrofit2

In Retrofit 2.0

I know it's possible that handler custom Param Annotations in `Converter.Factory`.

But can I handler custom Method Annotations like `CustomAnnotation` in below:

```
@CustomAnnotation
@POST("someUrl")
Observable<MyResponse> doSomeThing(@Body  body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that use a Proxy wrap the service create with Retrofit:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://example.com/")
.build();

ApiService rawService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

ApiService service = (ApiService) Proxy.newProxyInstance(rawService.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                rawService.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                new InvocationHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                        if (method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class) != null){
                            //handler the Annotations
                        }
                        return method.invoke(rawService,args);
                    }
                });
```